# How do I store a cookie in Play Framework?

Tags: java, cookies, playframework

I want to store an authentication token with Play Framework that outlives the current session, perhaps for days or even weeks - so that users don't have to login every time.

What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Please check a answer to close that question. It will help others too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The response object has a method setCookie, which does exactly what you want

```
response.setCookie("playlonglivecookie", yourData, "14d");
```

Remember, that the data stored in the cookie is not encrypted, so if you want to encrypt it, then use the `Crypto.sign` method. Which signs your code using the play framework secret key.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1.1/play/mvc/Http.Response.html#setCookie(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: How would you store a cookie if you want it shareable across all your subdomains? I'm trying to do this, but its not producing a cookie: response.setCookie("webLoggedIn", "true", "mydomain.org", "", 2592000, false, false);

Answer (score 7):

I would also advise you to have a look at the secure module provided in play-1.x/modules/secure and the file Secure.java... it provides a checkbox "remember me" in the login form which allows keeping you logged for eternity.

and the code of this function (specially the response.setCookie at the end):

```
public static void authenticate(@Required String username, String password, boolean remember) throws Throwable {
    // Check tokens
    Boolean allowed = false;
    try {
        // This is the deprecated method name
        allowed = (Boolean)Security.invoke("authentify", username, password);
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e ) {
        // This is the official method name
        allowed = (Boolean)Security.invoke("authenticate", username, password);
    }
    if(validation.hasErrors() || !allowed) {
        flash.keep("url");
        flash.error("secure.error");
        params.flash();
        login();
    }
    // Mark user as connected
    session.put("username", username);
    // Remember if needed
    if(remember) {
        response.setCookie("rememberme", Crypto.sign(username) + "-" + username, "30d");
    }
    // Redirect to the original URL (or /)
    redirectToOriginalURL();
}
```

Pascal

Answer (score 1):

With play > 2.5 *setCookie* is deprecated.

you can use instead:

```
Http.Response.setCookie(Http.Cookie cookie)
```

You can create a new cookie with the builder:

```
Http.Cookie.builder("name", "value").withMaxAge(15).build();
```

15 days is the expiration date

Reference: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/java/play/mvc/Http.Response.html#setCookie-play.mvc.Http.Cookie-

Example:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/test/java/play/mvc/CookieBuilderTest.java

Answer (score 0):

The response-object has some methods to help you. See [javadoc](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.0/play/mvc/Http.Response.html).